# SemanticException: no valid privileges when querying with a cast on Hive

Tags: hive, cloudera-cdh

I'm getting a weird error when running any query with a `cast` as a non-admin. For example:

```
select cast(site_id as decimal) from test_table limit 5;
```

In that example, `site_id` is a `bigint`, but the column type and the type it's being cast as make no difference at all. The query runs fine in the absence of a `cast`, and the admin can run the query without issues as well.

This is cdh 4.5.0, Hive 0.10.0.